# How to increase font size of whole content in NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to increase font size of text that comes from server and text is in html format.I used NSAttributedString for showing text.

```
NSRange rangeOfTitle = NSMakeRange(0,[catDescLabel length]);
```

NSMutableAttributedString *string1 =
[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:catDescLabel];

```
[string1 addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                        value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0]
                            range:rangeOfTitle];
```

I am attaching screenshot that how it look and i am also attaching screenshot how it look in Android.I want to increase font size of whole content. how can i do this ?
Could anyone give me any Idea or help. Much appreciated

[Android Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBUPb.png)

[iOS Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk3ZF.png)

Thanks ,

Answer (score 1):

> `addAttribute` ... but it seems it is not available for NSAttributedString

But it *is* available for NSMutableAttributedString.

That's how it is with all Cocoa immutable/mutable class pairs. The immutable member of the pair is, uh, immutable — that means you can't change anything about it. If you want to change something about it, convert it to the mutable member of the pair.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString2 = 
    [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString: attributedString1];
```

Comment: How can i change font of attributedString2. can you share me code

Comment: As you said yourself, call `addAttribute`. That's the point of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this…

```
NSMutableAttributedString *string1 =
[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Your string"];
[string1 addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
              value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0]
              range:NSMakeRange(5, 6)];
```

Update :

```
 [self.label setAttributedTitle:string1];
```

This will set the last two words in 20-point text; the rest of the string will use the default value (which I believe is 12 points). The thing that might be confusing about setting the text size is that you have to set the typeface and the size at the same time—each UIFont object encapsulates both of those properties.

And reference link for you
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Tasks/CreatingAttributedStrings.html

Comment: But i want to increase size of whole content. I use this but it's not work.

NSRange rangeOfTitle = NSMakeRange(0,[catDescLabel length]);

    NSMutableAttributedString *string1 =
    [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:catDescLabel];
    [string1 addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                    value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0]
                    range:rangeOfTitle];

Comment: You must set attributes title on label this is sample code please put this code into your project,  please check my updated answer

Comment: Vivek,I set content on UITextView
 self.tv.attributedText = string1;
If i increase font size via textview so it will not properly because server response is in html.
If i increase font size via NSMutableAttributedString it show html tag like <br>,<li> etc.

Comment: Now you should work on How to parse html data, please visit below link for your reference : https://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios

Comment: Yes i am able to parse html content.That's why i used NSMutableAttributedString and by default it's font size is 12 but when i try to increase font size i got this problem.
And UIlable has no method of setAttributedTitle

Comment: and there is no method of setAttributedTitle in UIlabel.